# Is there a compression algorithm that compresses multiple inputs into same output and when decompressing generates all of the original inputs?

Tags: algorithm, compression, collision

I find myself in need of an algorithm that performs lossy compression that can compress many different inputs into same compressed file and can generate all of the original inputs when decompressing the compressed file. It should be random enough that very different inputs map to one compressed file instead of similar ones. And when decompressing all of the initial inputs should be generated.

Let's say compressing an image in this manner would generate an output file that when decompressed produces a thousand (or some other number) of different random images with one of them being the original image.

EDIT:

Say we have extremely limited bandwidth but large computational resources and want to transmit a video. We send the first frame as normal and then compress rest of the frames first by normal compression algorithms and then with the algorithm described above. Decompressing the file would result in let's say a billion random images that are not similar to each other. From there using different filters, like checking for noise, we could compare the decompressed images to the first frame and find the one that's likely the correct second frame. I'm guessing this might not actually be efficient

Comment: Yes, it's technically possible. A 1000:1 map can only compress by a little over a byte on average over random inputs, though.

Comment: What you're asking for is possible, but what you probably want is not.  You can find all of the images that could have produced a .jpg, for example, but they'll all look pretty much the same and there will be more of them than there are atoms in the universe.  If you explain what you expect to do with this, maybe we can help.

Comment: Say we have extremely limited bandwidth but large computational resources and want to transmit a video. We send the first frame as normal and then compress rest of the frames first by normal compression algorithms and then with the algorithm described above. Decompressing the file would result in let's say a billion random images that are not similar to each other. From there using different filters, like checking for noise, we could compare the decompressed images to the first frame and find the one that's likely the correct second frame. I'm guessing this might not actually be efficient.

Comment: With a video, you might be better off transmitting the first frame, and then just transmit changes for the next group of frames -- that avoids re-sending unchanged backgrounds repeatedly.  Send a new full frame whenever there is a jump-cut or after n frames (for some value of n) to keep synchronisation.  There may already be video software that does this for you.

Comment: @rossum pretty much any decent video-compression does precisely what you're describing here. And so does streaming-software.